# how to provide prefix arg in magit while doing a pull

Tags: emacs, magit

I am trying to do a `git pull --rebase` from [`magit`](https://magit.github.io/) following these steps:

1. <kbd>C-x g</kbd> (bound to `magit-status`)
2. <kbd>F</kbd> (opens the submenu for pulling)

   The menu tells me that I can use the `-r` switch to do a rebase, so I do:
3. <kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>-r</kbd>

But the above doesn't seem to work. Any ideas how I can provide the `--rebase` flag ?

Thanks,
Murtaza

Comment: In my Emacs it's `F-rF` from status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @abo-abo's comment suggests, you do not need to press <kbd>C-u</kbd> to activate the `-r` switch (or any other switch in any submenu, for that matter). The correct sequence of steps is:

<kbd>C-x g</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> <kbd>-r</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd>

I think what might have tripped you up is the fact that `magit` calls switches (such as `-r`) "prefixes" in the message that appears in the echo area when bringing up a submenu:

> Type a prefix key to toggle it. Run 'actions' with their prefixes. '?' for more help.